# Trouble with aliases and opencv

Tags: command-line, libraries, alias, opencv

I have an alias defined to compile an opencv program which goes like this

```
alias gcv='g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect'
```

Then I go on to type

```
gcv imageshow.cpp
```

I get this long list of errors

[image]

But when I use the same command specified in the alias with the .cpp(source code) file in between the Include and Library files ([following the suggestion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824439/c-math-linker-problems-on-ubuntu-11-10)), everything works like a charm.

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv imageshow.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui
```

Now typing the long command, which gets even bigger as complexity increases, every time is getting difficult, please help me in getting the alias to work or suggest any other alternative.

Comment: try `g++ imageshow.cpp (pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv)` also try to add a white space at the end of your alias string.

Comment: No luck with either.. I'm Getting errors.. g++: error: pkg-config -libs opencv: No such file or directory.

Comment: The space after the alias makes no difference.

Comment: just try to try only `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` but you appear to missing the necessary packages to develop with opencv, install those packages with `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev` and after that run `sudo ldconfig`

Comment: Every other package is present.. I get a long list on executing the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this without using aliases:

```
g++ imageshow.cpp -o imageshow `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Comment: Oh crap.. all this while every other place I saw this command I thought that was a "single quote".. When I saw u stressing on the same thing once again.. I copied and pasted it and took off time and realize that it was "Tilde".. Thanks a TON :D

Comment: if you are confused by this you can always use an equivalent version which is `g++ imageshow.cpp -o imageshow $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv)`

Comment: I'd say change the backticks to `$(...)` in the answer. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple script instead of the alias?

file `gcv` in `~/bin/`

```
#/bin/sh 
g++ $* -I/usr/local/include/opencv -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect
```

Alternatively if you're using `zsh` you can use a function defined in your `.zshrc` file:

```
gcv() { 
    g++ $* -I/usr/local/include/opencv -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect;
}
```

**Automated compiler and linker flags**

If you're having linker issues, you can also incorporate `pkg-config` here:

```
#/bin/sh 
g++ $* `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

**Spaces in filenames**

While other posts on similar issues [exist](https://superuser.com/questions/89570/making-bash-script-for-handle-filenames-with-spaces-or-workaround), handling spaces in the filenames is
not trivial so I thought I'd recap an elegant solution here; specifically I found 
that making use of the `IFS` variable helps tremendously.

So making a small addition to end up with

```
#/bin/sh 
IFS=$';'
g++ $* `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

solves issues with spaces in filenames too!

Comment: I'm giving it a shot right now.. I need some clarity on this.. Is it a shell script ?? I name it gcv.sh and put it in ~/bin ?? I am using the default shell so its Bash right ??

Comment: @Bhargav - Yes it's a shell script. You need to make it executable using `chmod +x gcv` (Remove the .sh if you want to invoke using just gcv!). And yes put it in your `~/bin` directory, which your `.bashrc` should already have appended to the `$PATH`.

Comment: Now.. the last thing u said about the $PATH.. I don't seem to find it in my .bashrc file.. What do I do ??

Comment: You can add it yourself; at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file add `export PATH=$PATH:~/bin` - it means that any executable scripts in your bin folder will be callable without having to specify the full path

Comment: Problem: If I have the script in the same folder as the source code its working great else its not..
ERROR: bash: ./gcv: No such file or directory..

Comment: That means it's not been added to your path properly. Just to confirm: 1) You placed the script in the `~/bin` folder, 2) You added `export PATH=~/bin:$PATH` to the bottom of `.bashrc` (after which this will work in **NEW** terminals - type `export PATH=~/bin:$PATH` into any old terminals if you want it to work there)

Comment: Also you can confirm that `.bashrc` is being sourced correctly by typing `echo $PATH` and confirming that ~/bin is in the colon delimited list.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4321/discussion-between-bhargav-and-mutzmatron)

Answer (score 0):

The post on creating a shell script wasn't very clear .. This was the simple procedure I followed to create a script of my own and it works even if the filename have spaces in it..

Here's what I did

- `mkdir ~/bin`
- `nano ~/bin/gcv`
- `sudo chmod u+x ~/bin/gcv`
- Type in the following into the script

  > ```
  >     #!/bin/bash   
  >     g++ "$@" `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv`
  > ```
- `export PATH=$PATH:~/bin`
- Type `echo $PATH` and make sure u see `~/bin` listed in the output u get.
- Type `alais` if you see any aliases by the name `gcv` use the command `unalias gcv` or else u'll have trouble using `gcv` as a command to compile the code, May be aliases have higher priority than scripts.
- Even if my file-names have spaces in them the script won't have an issue.